# componentWillUpdate()時に子のcomponentにpropsでstateを渡したい

Tags: reactjs

あるcomponentでcomponentWillUpdate()をし、
state、またはpropsが更新されたタイミングで子のcomponentにpropsで親のcomponentのstateを渡したいのですがどうすればできますか？

Answer (score 1):

React単体でどうにかできなくもないですが，要件的にRedux使ったほうがいいんじゃないでしょうか？Reduxじゃないと今後複雑さに耐えられないにおいがプンプンします…

Reduxであればこの手の問題は簡単に解決できますね。